# CSS3 Multiple Transitions with Multiple DIVS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to either link 2 `div` elements in CSS by hovering over one `div` to activate 2 others

OR

Link 2 different transitions together so one works and then the other on 2 `div` elements when I hover over a third. At the moment, I can only make one at a time work but not both.

---

Just to clarify, I need to start a chain of events using CSS3 Transitions. 
I need to trigger  using the hover on div 1 to set off a transition on div 2 then after that one on div 3.
I can trigger both at the same time and use Delay on the third to make the chain work.
At the moment only the transition on div 2 works but nothing happens on div 3?

HTML

```
<html>
 <div id="1"></div>
 <div id="2"></div>
 <div id="3"></div>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#1:hover + #2{Transition; }(works great!)
#1:hover + #3{Transition; } (No joy :( )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the divs are always going to be siblings you could try something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="div1">
  Hello!
</div>
<div class="div2">
  Hello!
</div>
<div class="div3">
  Hello!
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
  background:red;
}
.div1:hover {
  background:blue;
}
.div1:hover ~ .div2 {
  background:purple;
}
.div1:hover ~ .div3 {
  background:thistle;
}
.div2 {
  background:green;
}
.div3 {
  background:yellow;
}
```

Working codepen here:

http://codepen.io/alexbaulch/pen/xFkHj

**UPDATE:**

I have edited the code so that the hover effect is different for each element, as per the comment.

Comment: This wont work because class 2 and 3 have different transitions not the same otherwise yes this would work great

Comment: I have updated the CodePen to reflect the changes you asked for as well as the code above. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
.div1 { styling }
.div1:hover .div2 { styling }
.div1:hover .div3 { styling }
.div2 { styling }
.div3 { styling }
```

As simple as that, you can add all the transitions you want.

Comment: I tried this before but no joy :( it may be multi transitions that it doesn't like?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to apply styles to the siblings of the hovered `div`. Here's how you can do this:

#### HTML

```
<section>
  <div>DIV 1</div>
  <div>DIV 2</div>
  <div>DIV 3</div>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
section {
    display: inline-block; /* shrink wraps around inner divs */
}

/* select all divs that are not being hovered */
section:hover > div:not(:hover) {
    ...
}

/* select hovered div, if needed */
section:hover > div:hover {
    ...
}
```

This will work for any number of siblings, not just 3!

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Surjikal/a7AG4/5/

#### Note

If you add spacing around the `div` elements, then you will be able to hover on the `section` element without hovering over a `div`. This will cause the `section:hover > div:not(:hover)` rule to be applied to all `div` elements inside the `section`.

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Surjikal/jbXnj/

To work around this, you'll need to wrap your `div` elements in a container.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Surjikal/B4MnD/

Comment: I'm not sure about this one and how it would work with transitions hover over div1 to start a chain of transitions in div 2 and then div 3?

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't understand your question correctly. Do you need this to be generic or will you always have 3 divs? If you will always have 3 divs, do you want div 1 to transition, then div 3, when you hover over div 2?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/mac1175/afGyu/

This use :hover pseudo class.

### CSS

```
div {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: skyblue;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Yes sure use the hover pseudo class but so it works on 2 other divs that have different transitions